# failed to builed project solution en godot

Tags: c#

Cuando voy a ejecutar el script(en este caso con c# version mono)y me
aparece este error(el que esta en el titulo) nisiquiera compila para decirme si tengo errores ni nada.
esto fue lo unico que encontre

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: No se encuentran los ensamblados de referencia para .NETFramework,Version=v4.7. Para resolver este problema, instale el Paquete de desarrollador (SDK o Paquete de compatibilidad) de esta versión de .NET Framework o redestine la aplicación. Para descargar los paquetes de desarrollador de .NET Framework, vaya a https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [E:\Proyectogodot\tutorial\tutorial.csproj]
```

Comment: Ya verificaste si tienes instalado el SDK correcto? En la configuración de la aplicación, sabes si está apuntando a Net 4.7? Qué has intentado? No nos das suficiente información para ayudarte

Comment: El mensaje de error dice todo... no entiendo cuál es tu duda.

Comment: amigo entiendo instale lo que me pide .net 4.7 pero sigo el mismo error la app en godot no corre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lees el error veras que lo dice claramente:

> error MSB3644: No se encuentran los ensamblados de referencia para
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7

E incluso te dice como repararlo:

> Para resolver este problema, instale el Paquete de desarrollador (SDK
> o Paquete de compatibilidad) de esta versión de .NET Framework o
> redestine la aplicación. Para descargar los paquetes de desarrollador
> de .NET Framework, vaya a https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

En palabras simple, estas intentando compilar una aplicacion a un framework que no tienes instalado. La app que intentas compilar esta apuntado al framework 4.7 o tiene dependencias del 4.7 pero en tu PC no tienes instalado el framework 4.7.

Para saber la versiones de los framework que tienes instalado ve a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`.

En mi caso se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi que tienes 2 opciones.

**1 -** Bajas la version del framework al proyecto a una version de framework que si tengas instalado. Para hacer esto, dale click derecho al proyecto **-> Propiedades -> Aplicacion** y en el combo Plataforma de destino, elige la version del framework que tienes instalado.

**2 -** Instalas la version del framework que te esta exigiendo que es la 4.7. Puedes descargarlo [AQUI](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net47).